# CDK StepFunction Task: How to list all objects of a bucket and filter by suffix?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-step-functions

In a step function I want to first list all `.png` files in `mybucket` and then process them in a subsequent lambda task.

Is there an easy way to pass only a filtered list of objects from a `listObjects` task to the next one? I suspect `resultSelector` should be able to do it but I don't see how.

This is the list task so far:

```
new tasks.CallAwsService(this, 'ListObjects', {
      service: 's3',
      action: 'listObjectsV2',
      parameters: {
        Bucket: mybucket.bucketName,
      },
      iamResources: [mybucket.bucketArn],
      iamAction: 's3:ListBucket',
    });
```

I can easily ignore all files not ending with `.png` in the lambda itself but that seems not like a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that the response of the `listObjectsV2` API call is paginated, so sending just one request will likely not yield the whole list. To work around this, you would need to implement another step that would run the call again with the `NextToken` param and check if the token is empty every time [(example)](https://dev.to/stevensmiley/handling-paginated-api-responses-in-aws-step-functions-1emf).

Since the CDK `tasks.CallAwsService` wrapper is essentially a pre-baked Lambda function in itself, it can be beneficial to just implement this step as a separate custom lambda, where you can properly handle the `listObjectsV2` pagination and filter results to your liking. `ResultSelector` is a JSONPath expression, which is itself also limited compared to what can be achieved in code.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I think I will implement my own lambda for listing then